# Chrome Extension I can't get the tab title correctly in my custom extension history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a plugin for Chrome and it has History feature in the plugin.  For example, clicking the button creates a new tab and saves the URL address in the history.  So this function works fine.  But I want to get the document.title data of the tab that was opened in the past instead of the URL address.  I tried doing this with `tabs[tabs.length-1].title` but it didn't get the title of the opened tab.  Instead it got the title of the last tab that was already open.  ***I guess this is the problem because the tab is not open yet.***  How can I solve this?  Can you help me please?

**This is my create tab function (If the tab is already open, don't open it again.):**

```
function openTab(tab_url) {
    var isTabActive = false;
    var tabId = 0;
    var tabTitle = "";
    totalHistoryContent++;
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) { 
        for(var i=0;i<tabs.length;i++) {
            if(tabs[i].url.toLowerCase().includes(tab_url.toLowerCase()) == true) {
                isTabActive = true;
                tabId = tabs[i].id;
                tabTitle = tabs[i].title; // WORKING NICE
                break;
            }
        }

        if(isTabActive == false) {
            chrome.tabs.create({ url:tab_url });
            tabTitle = tabs[tabs.length - 1].title; // NOT WORKING CORRECTLY
        } else{
            chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});
            chrome.tabs.reload(tabId);
        }
        alert(tabTitle);
    });

    if(tab_url !== "chrome-extension://" + chrome.runtime.id + "/popup.html" && tab_url !== "chrome://extensions/?id=" + chrome.runtime.id) {
        setHistory(tabTitle,49); //THIS FUNCTION SAVE TITLE TO HISTORY
    }
}
```

Comment: Anybody else???

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways that you can handle this problem is sending an ajax request to the page's url

```
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open('GET', 'tab_url', true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (
        this.readyState == 4 &&
        ((this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) ||
            this.status == 304)
    ) {
        var data = this.responseText;
        var contentType = this.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"); //no i18n
        if (contentType && contentType.match('text/html')) {
            var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/html");
            console.log(doc.title);
        }
    }
};
xmlHttp.send();
```

Note: This may throw CORS error at most pages, so don't forget to add "<all_urls>" in permissions in manifest(assuming you are using manifest V2).

```
"permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
],
```

If you are using manifest V3, which is recommended, refer this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#host-permissions) regarding permission

**Other way** is to send a message from [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-create) success callback to content script, if you don't use content script you have to inject code. In message response you can send the document's title using `document.title`.

Either way both will be asynchronous...